# Dynamical view according to data

Tags: javascript, data-modeling

For a object have multiple attributes, for example, a shoe may have different `color`, `size` and etc.

Now when we tried to display the shoe, and make the customer can choose different attributes, we use radio(the simplest): https://jsfiddle.net/mwqy6217/

But how to make the availability of the view according to the data?

For example, when the red shoes are sold out, the `red` radio should be un-checkable. So are different sizes.

We can use this data structure to represent the shoe: `{shoe:{name:'',available:['red','black','40','41']}}`.

However different attributes may have relationship with each other, for example, red shoes with 40 size have been sold out, while black shoes with 40 size have not.
I think this data structure:

`{shoe:{name:'',available:{color:{red:[40,41,42]},black:[42,43]}}}`

As the shoe may have other attributes like 'weight', and an attributes may have 10+ options.

So how to represent this kind of relationship in the database and make them readable by the front engineer to build the view?

Update:

https://jsfiddle.net/xqtgqzt2/

See the live demo, all the available options is pre-defined as:

```
var options= [
    ["A1","B1","C1","D1"],
    ["A1","B3","D2"],
    ["A2","B1","C3","D2"]
];
```

Now how to  make the radio button state changed according to the options? For example, when A1 is checked, only B1 B3 can be checked(enabled), when A1 B1 are checked, only C1 D1 can be checked.

Comment: With your options array, what does it means ? Something like: if I select option A1, il will only be able to select B1=>C1=>D1 or B3=>D2 or something else ?

Comment: so also the previous level select, will be a filter for future selection, it mean if A1 - B1 is seleted, the user can only select C1 - D1, even if from B1 also C3 - D2 can be selected, it will getting more restricted between levels?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To display your radio buttons regarding the option multidimensionnal array, you can do something like :

```js
var options = [
    ["A1", "B1", "C1", "D1"],
    ["A1", "B3", "D2"],
    ["A2", "B1", "C3", "D2"]
];
var firstLevel = [];
var selectedList = [];
//Enable first options, disable the others
$("input[type=radio]").each(function (indexInput) {
    var that = this;
    that.disabled = true;
    $.each(options, function (index, value) {
        firstLevel.push(value[0]);
        if (value[0] == that.value) {
            that.disabled = false;
        }
    });
});
//on check radio, change states
$("input[type=radio]").on("click", function () {
    var thatClicked = this;
    if (firstLevel.indexOf(thatClicked.value) !== -1) {
        $('input[type=radio]').removeAttr('checked');
        $(thatClicked).prop('checked', true);
    }
    var possibleOptions = [];
    selectedList.push(thatClicked.value);
    $.each(options, function (index, value) {

        possibleOptions = possibleOptions.concat(value[0]);
        var posInArray = value.indexOf(thatClicked.value);
        if (posInArray !== -1 && typeof value[posInArray + 1] !== 'undefined') {
            //check previous options
            $.each(selectedList, function (indexSelectedList, valueSelectedList) {
                if (value.indexOf(valueSelectedList) !== -1) {
                    possibleOptions = possibleOptions.concat(value[posInArray + 1]);
                }
            });

        }
    });
    $("input[type=radio]").each(function (indexInput) {
        if (possibleOptions.indexOf(this.value) !== -1) {
            this.disabled = false;
        } else {
            this.disabled = true;
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.section {
    padding: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
label {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <div class="section">
        <label>
            <input type="radio" value="A1" /> <span>A1</span>

        </label>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" value="A2" /> <span>A2</span>

        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="section">
        <label>
            <input type="radio" value="B1" /> <span>B1</span>

        </label>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" value="B2" /> <span>B2</span>

        </label>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" value="B3" /> <span>B3</span>

        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="section">
        <label>
            <input type="radio" value="C1" /> <span>C1</span>

        </label>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" value="C2" /> <span>C2</span>

        </label>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" value="C3" /> <span>C3</span>

        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="section">
        <label>
            <input type="radio" value="D1" /> <span>D1</span>

        </label>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" value="D2" /> <span>D2</span>

        </label>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="info">var options= [ ["A1","B1","C1","D1"], ["A1","B3","D2"], ["A2","B1","C3","D2"] ];</div>
```

Comment: Both A1 and A2 should be checkable.

Comment: @hguser You means always checkable ?

Comment: User should have the ability to switch from one option to another.  In your example, once A1 is checked, I can not check A2 again unless I refresh the page

Comment: @hguser Updated my aswer to allow the user to switch beetween the first level of options

Comment: `var options = [
    ["A1", "B1", "C1", "D1"],
    ["A1", "B3", "D2"],
    ["A2", "B1", "C3", "D2"],
 ["B1", "C3", "D2"]
];`  The order of the option are not complete all the time. I tried the following options, and some strange behavior occurred.

Comment: @hguser Nothing strange with that. Your B1 option can be a first option, that's all.

Comment: Oh yes, i saw the thing, but it's quite tricky to find a way for that

Comment: :). It is really a hard job.

Comment: @hguser It's not possible to know when the user want to select `B1` as first or second option. So you should have complete path in your array.

Comment: Finally we use tree structure as the representation.

Answer (score 0):

I would set my data up similar to your second option, however because the first thing they are going to care about is size (you can't change your shoe size), I would show available colours for a size, rather than available sizes for a colour. You would first of all list all availability because if a customer knows that a size 9 green "happy shoe" is potentially available, they might come back later to buy it. You would then loop through the available options to change whether that size or colour is available.

Here's the data set up:

```
var objShoes = [{
    name: 'Happy Shoe',
    sizes: [9,10,11,12,13],
    colours: ['red','blue','green'],
    available: [{
        size: 9,
        colours: ['red']
    },{
        size: 10,
        colours: ['red', 'blue']
    },{
        size: 11,
        colours: ['blue']
    },{
        size: 12,
        colours: ['red', 'blue']
    },{
        size: 13,
        colours: ['red']
    }]
}, {
    name: 'Scary Shoe',
    sizes: [8,9,10,11,12],
    colours: ['black','grey'],
    available: [{
        size: 8,
        colours: ['black']
    }]
}];
```

[Here's an example of how that could work](https://jsfiddle.net/xqtgqzt2/8/), although I used select boxes instead of radio buttons. They're neater :).

Comment: color and size are only two attributes I used for example, in fact, there are 5+ color-size like attributes.

Answer (score 0):

The easier way IMHO is to separate the data itself from the definition of an attribute, and not having a hierarchy between attributes. To do this you'll need every attribute value to have a unique id.

In this example I use the index of every attribute in the array as an id to reference it from the `availability` object.

```
{
    attributes: [
        {value: "red",   type: "colour"}, // 0
        {value: "green", type: "colour"}, // 1
        {value: "black", type: "colour"}, // 2
        {value: "brown", type: "colour"}, // 3

        {value: 40, type: "size"}, // 4
        {value: 41, type: "size"}, // 5
        {value: 42, type: "size"}, // 6
        {value: 43, type: "size"}, // 7
        {value: 44, type: "size"}, // 8

        {value: true,  type: "with_shoelace"}, // 9
        {value: false, type: "with_shoelace"}, // 10
    ],

    products: [
        {
            name: 'some random shoe',
            availability: {
                0: [4, 7, 8, 9], // red is compatible with 40, 43 and 44, only with shoelace
                1: [4, 5, 9, 10], // green is compatible with 40, 43 and 44, with or without shoelace
                ...
                6: [2, 3, 9, 10], // 42 can be black or brown, with or without shoelace
                7: [0, 1, 10], // 43 can be red or green, without shoelace
                ...
                10: [1, 4, 6, 7, 8], // ...
            }
        },
        {
            name: 'another shoe',
            availability: {
                ...
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

On the GUI, you'll have to intersect the `availability` arrays from each checked attribute in order to determine which option is usable.